# Make google search term with forward slash

Tags: seo, google-search

Wanted to see if it was possible to make my site searchable including a special character, in this case it's a forward slash '/'

Say i have a common 2 character term like 'AB', but I want to optimize and appear in searches for 'A/B' specifically. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What does the slash mean in your search term?  Slashes have several meanings including "either or", "and", or "per".

Comment: It would be 'silent' if that makes sense. Like A/B testing or A/C.

Comment: In "A/B" testing it means "A or B" testing.

Comment: Sure it means A or B testing but people call it "A B testing" either way in my situation the slash is silent.

Answer (score 1):

Google just ignores slashes.   If you search for "A/B testing" on Google, sites come up that use the term in a variety of ways:

- A/B Testing
- A B Testing

I can search for variations and get the same set of results on Google:

- A/B testing
- A B testing
- AB testing

Use the term in your page written with a slash the way that it is most commonly used.  That is what looks most natural for users.  In the case of "A/B testing" the slash is present in about 90% of sites.

Google will just do the right thing and display the same results when people search for it in different ways.